# Index (Home) page not displayed when running wordpress in a subdirectory

Tags: directory, domain, site-url

I'm running my wordpress site in a subdirectory. Do do that i followed the instructions here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Before i had the url:

```
mydomain.com/wordpress
```

now its

```
mydomain.com
```

that basicly works but theres a difference between before and after. With the first version when i entered the site the recent posts were displayed (the home page).

when going to the page now, i only get:

> Nothing Found Apologies, but no results were found. Perhaps searching
>   will help find a related post.

any suggestions on how to get the recent posts displayed when accessing mydomain.com ?

Comment: Is it the same database?

Comment: Yes i didnt change the database. I had wordpress installed in a subdirectory. And now i used the above guide to make it the homepage.